# Why does Everyplay indicate recording is not supported in this code?

Tags: unity, android

I am using Everyplay in my game and when I run my game on mobile. It showing me as recording supported as false. I put the Client ID and client secret as well and checked on Android enabled. Can somebody tell me whats wrong with my code or did I miss something? I am using onePlus2 with marshmallow. And using Unity 4.6.4f1 with latest SDK of Everyplay from Asset Store (2110-1530). Here's my code:

```
private bool readyForRecord = false;
private bool recordingInProgress = false;

void OnEnable(){

    Everyplay.ReadyForRecording += EveryPlayRadyForRecording;
    Everyplay.RecordingStarted += RecordingStarted;
    Everyplay.RecordingStopped += RecordingStopped;

}

void OnDisable(){

    Everyplay.ReadyForRecording -= EveryPlayRadyForRecording;
    Everyplay.RecordingStarted -= RecordingStarted;
    Everyplay.RecordingStopped -= RecordingStopped;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Everyplay.Initialize ();
    Debug.Log  ("Is recording supported =  " + Everyplay.IsRecordingSupported ());
  }

#region Recording Operations

public void StartRecording(){
    if (Everyplay.IsReadyForRecording ()) {

        Debug.Log ("Recording Started");

        recordingInProgress = true;
        Everyplay.StartRecording ();

    } 

    if (recordingInProgress)
        StopRecording ();


}

public void PauseRecording(){
    Debug.Log ("Recording Paused!");

    if(!Everyplay.IsPaused())
        Everyplay.PauseRecording ();

}

public void ResumeRecording(){
    Debug.Log ("Resuming Recording");

    if (Everyplay.IsPaused ())
          Everyplay.ResumeRecording ();

}

public void StopRecording(){
    if (recordingInProgress) {
        Everyplay.StopRecording ();
        recordingInProgress = false;
        Debug.Log ("Recording Stopped!");
    }

}

public void ShowRecording(){
    Debug.Log  ("Showing Recording...please wait!");

    if (!recordingInProgress)
        Everyplay.ShowSharingModal ();

}

#endregion

#region Everyplay Callback Events

private void EveryPlayRadyForRecording(bool ready){
    Debug.Log ("Ready for recording =  " + ready);

    if (ready)
        readyForRecord = ready;

}

private void RecordingStarted(){   
    Debug.Log ("Recording started"); 
}

private void RecordingStopped(){
    Debug.Log  ("Recording stopped"); 
}

private void SharingInProgress(int videoID, float progress){
    Debug.Log  (" Uploading " + videoID + " " + progress + "%" + " completed.");

}

private void SharingCompleted(int videoID){
    Debug.Log  (" Uploading Sucessful =  " + videoID);    
}

#endregion
```